# request for assistance, postgres

Tags: postgresql

I am new to postgres and come up with the following question. My view has departure cities and arrival cities. I need to answer the question: which cities do not have direct flights between each other? The output of view "routes" is following:

```
select distinct 
    departure_city,
    departure_airport,
    arrival_airport,
    arrival_city 
from routes
order by departure_city asc
```

here is the output:

[image: click here to see the outcome]

My logic is as following: select all arrival cities for one specific departure city. Exclude this outcome (arrival cities) for distinct list of cities. But I have no idea how to put this logic into sql request. Thank you in advance.

Comment: You're looking for [`EXCEPT`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-union.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would first get the list of all cities, then report all pairs from the cross join that have no connecting flight:

```
WITH cities(city) AS (
   SELECT departure_city FROM routes
   UNION
   SELECT arrival_city FROM routes
)
SELECT c1.city, c2.city
FROM cities AS c1 JOIN cities AS c2
   ON c1.city <> c2.city
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM routes AS r
                  WHERE r.departure_city = c1.city
                    AND r.arrival_city = c2.city);
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked! Can you, please, explain what does "SELECT 1 FROM routes AS r" means? I tried to replace "1" by "*" and did not notice changes.

Comment: Right, the result is irrelevant. It is only important if the subquery returns rows or not.